# More C# to VB conversion woes when working with Mediator helpers in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, linq, mvvm

Working through the whole concept of the mediator pattern and its use in wpf, and with thanks to those who have helped thus far I stumbled across an article by Sacha Barber on Code Project in which he takes the Mediator but adapts it slightly to make it a little more versatile.

I have been able to follow the logic of his argument and (rather nicely for a change) almost all of his c# examples convert nicely.  All bar one of course! and that one being his example of how you actually register for the mediator.  For those who haven't seen the article you can reference it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35277/MVVM-Mediator-Pattern)

the piece of C# causing the problems is within the constructor of his example shown below

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Input;


   namespace MediatorDemo
   {

   public class ReadersViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private String readText = String.Empty;


      public ReadersViewModel()
       {
           //register to the mediator for the 
           //UserWroteSomething message
          Mediator.Instance.Register(

              //Callback delegate, when message is seen
              (Object o) =>
               {
                 ReadText = (String)o;
                }, ViewModelMessages.UserWroteSomething);
       }


      public String ReadText
       {
          get { return readText; }
           set
            {
                readText = value;
              NotifyChanged("ReadText");
           }
      }
   }
}
```

And Telerik's online converter give out the following

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Input


Namespace MediatorDemo
    Public Class ReadersViewModel
        Inherits ViewModelBase
        Private m_readText As [String] = [String].Empty


        Public Sub New()
            'register to the mediator for the 
            'UserWroteSomething message

            'Callback delegate, when message is seen
            Mediator.Instance.Register(Function(o As [Object]) 
            ReadText = DirectCast(o, [String])

End Function, ViewModelMessages.UserWroteSomething)
        End Sub


        Public Property ReadText() As [String]
            Get
                Return m_readText
            End Get
            Set
                m_readText = value
                NotifyChanged("ReadText")
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Again I presume that this must be a hang up in the way that c# and vb write Linq, but I can't fathom what it is.

I'd welcome any suggestions.

Many Thanks

EDIT 1

Well I've been doing some playing around and came up with the following:

```
 Mediator.Instance.Register(Function(ByVal o As Object) ReadText = DirectCast(o


,[String]),ViewModelMessages.UserWroteSomething)
```

This begs the obvious question, is it right?

EDIT 2

This is the definition of the register method which I think will throw some extra light on what the code is trying to do.

```
   ''' <summary>
    ''' Registers a Colleague to a specific message
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="callback">The callback to use 
    ''' when the message it seen</param>
    ''' <param name="message">The message to 
    ''' register to</param>
    Public Sub Register(callback As Action(Of [Object]), message As ViewModelMessages)
        internalList.AddValue(message, callback)
    End Sub
```

Comment: This line is weird: "End Function,ViewModelMessages.UserWroteSomething" Usually it's just "End Function". You might have some spacing issues.

Comment: Also, there's no function to end. The end sub correspond to the New() sub. So that's a strange line to pop out of no where. Looking at your C# stuff, it's probably the short hand for the "viewmodelmessages" line that got translated badly.

Comment: Oh I know it's odd, but if you take the C# original and run it through Telerik's online converter (which in fairness is pretty darn good most of the time) you'll end up with what you see in the lower window. On further reflection it's probably a lambda expression rather than linq, but it still has me thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The code below is valid VB for an Action(of Object) parameter.

```
Mediator.Instance.Register(Sub(o As Object) ReadText = TryCast(o, String), ViewModelMessages.UserWroteSomething)
```

Using `Function(o as Object)` in your lambda corresponds to a `Predicate(of Object)` type, which probably is causing you a type mismatch problem.

Inside the lambda, if the `TryCast` fails, then the string variable `ReadText` will be set to `Nothing`.

Also, remove the '[' and ']' from around keywords like `Object` and `String`, because that syntax could cause the system to treat the symbols as differently defined. It looks more like you want the CLR `Object` and `String` types there, from what I can tell.